# JSON api oembed youtube

Tags: json, embed, plugin-json-api

I want to write a plugin that uses the Wordpress5 methods of embedding media. I want a block where users can insert URLs. Then use WordPress methods to find the provider and get the embeddable iframe.

Like you post a url from e.g. youtube, twitter to your post and you get an iframe with the embedded video, also determine if it is a valid youtube url. I do not want to use other plugins.

From browsing the gutenberg code. I found that the embed blocks [use the oembed api](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/72955796a533bdbc198a82a35074c0a0479b63c0/packages/e2e-test-utils/src/mocks/create-embedding-matcher.js#L42). However I fail at sending requests to the `/wp-json/oembed/1.0/proxy` as well as the `/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed` endpoint.

From the [gutenberg test source I assume](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/da8555d258edbe676fa079fb51252f918ae032e1/packages/e2e-tests/specs/editor/various/embedding.test.js#L36) that it should return json with the iframe html and the provider.

How, if at all, can I use that api endpoint?

Comment: Can you rephrase? It's unclear if you're trying to add new OEmbed providers to WordPress, trying to turn your WordPress into an OEmbed provider, or trying to add a new block that uses OEmbed, please clarify what you're trying to do and what the goal is. It also looks like the last sentence in your first paragraph was cut off

Comment: I edited my question. Hope it is clearer now.